# Why do I have to cast an address into an integer to make it assignable?

Tags: c++, pointers

Pointers store addresses, either on the heap or on the stack. After some search, I tried to understand what is an "address"; I found it is just an integer value mapping a memory area.

- I wonder: as long as an address is just an integer why can't I assign it to an integer variable:

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  using std::cout;
  using std::endl;

  int main()
  {
      int  a    = 1024;
      int* ptrA = &a;

      cout << "ptrA: " << ptrA << endl;   //  0018FF44
      cout << "*ptrA: " << *ptrA << endl; //  1024
      cout << "&a: " << &a << endl;       //  0018FF44
      cout << "a: " << a << endl;         //  1024

  //  int b = ptrA;      // why this is incorrect
      int b = (int)ptrA; // why I need this?

      cout << "b: " << std::hex << b << endl; //  18FF44

      // so b is identic to ptrA!

      std::cout << std::endl;
      return 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: @George I think he means to say they can hold addresses of automatic or dynamic objects.

Comment: Are you asking why you need the cast?

Comment: @NathanOliver yes that is it what I meant

Comment: I would avoid the use of the word heap in that context for c++ as it doesn't really make any sense, as @NathanOliver said, automatic/dynamic memory storage makes things much clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two primary reasons.

1. An `int` may not be big enough to store a pointer value. This is an implementation-specific detail. It is still common to find C++ implementations on 64-bit platforms, with 64-bit memory addresses, where an `int` is only 32 bits.
2. Type safety. One of the reasons different types exist it for the compiler to catch obvious mistakes, such as using a pointer to one class when a pointer to a different class is expected. If all pointers, to every object, were just plain ints, these errors will be uncaught.

Answer (score 4):

> I found it is just an integer value that is the way memory is mapped.

Usually yes, but this is *not* necessarily true.

The C++ standard allows many problematic things, like eg. bits in the variable that are not used for storing the value, specific values that are invalid and can cause crashes etc., and so on. Pointers and integers could differ in that points.

A part of it is an actual problem on commonly used platforms: `int` and pointers can have different sizes (eg. 4 and 8 bytes).

> I wonder: as long as an address is just an integer why can't I assign
>   it to an integer variable

...and that's why you can't do this: There no guarantee that assigning the value in memory is possible and/or makes sense.

On x86-like platforms, as long as you use the correct int size, there are no real problems, but C++ is more than x86...

Answer (score 1):

You can, but only for integer types that are large enough to hold the value of the pointer. On 64-bit systems, pointers are 64 bits long, whereas an `int` is typically only 32 bits. While you could use a `long int` or `long long int` (depending on which kind of processor and which operating system), there is also the type `intptr_t` from `inttypes.h`, which is guaranteed to be able to hold the value of a pointer.

Note however that you should almost never have to put the value of a pointer into an integer variable.

Answer (score 0):

From the C language standard ISO/IEC9899 §6.3.2.3/p6 Pointers:

> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as
>   previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the
>   result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behaviour is
>   undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any
>   integer type.

As the standard states there are certain issues when converting a pointer to an integer.

1. The result is implementation-defined.
2. The result may not be representable by the integer type, which leads in undefined behaviour.
3. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer type.

Having in mind the above reasons, C++ as a strongly typed language forbids an implicit conversion of such kind, in order for accidental behaviour to be avoided. It is allowed though, to do explicit conversions of such kind in the spirit that as a programmer you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

A type is defined by the data representation that it uses **and** by the operations that can be applied to it. "An address is just an integer" is about the data representation, not about operations. An address is **not** an integer.

Answer (score -1):

Well c++ is a strong typed language. Of course an adress of a pointer is just, in most cases, an hexadecimal representation of an integer which represents a spot in the memory. The type of data will tell the compiler how much space it needs to save on the stack to store the variable. Pointers being usually 4 bytes on 32 bits machines.

As for the conversion, it is simply how the language is made. A pointer can only point to the location of a same-type variable initially. The only exception is void.

As for the conversion using the cast, it is required for ehat has been mentionned above, c++ is a strongly-typed language and must know what type it is dealing with.

Comment: `Of course an adress is just an hexadecimal representation` Of course *not*.

Comment: Well in c++ it kinda is. Sure you can have your address as 32 bits in the machine, but in c++, unless you ask not to, an adress will always be represented by an hexadecimal string. Which is not completly false.

Comment: Sorry, but that's even more nonsense. It not for us to choose how many bits the address will have in the machine. And, like any number, it can have any representation. Hex, Dez, Binary, Morse code, images of potatoes, anything. And, when printing numbers during runtime, unless I ask for something else, the default is decimal for all builtin output stuff.